# BASH: Dialog input in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, dialog

I am trying to get user input from the inputbox using the `dialog` command to create a directory in a bash script. Currently I have the following code:

```
 rm -f ans.txt
 dialog --title "Create Directory" --inputbox "Enter the directory name:" 8 40 2>ans.txt
 val=$(<ans.txt)
 mkdir $val
```

It works, however it requires the creation (and deletion) of a temporary file. Can I store the user input from `dialog` directly into `$val` without using a temporary file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you will use command substitution to obtain the output of a command into a variable. Like this:

```
date=$(date)
```

which writes the output of the `date` command to the variable `$date`.

But if we try the same with the dialog `dialog` command:

```
user_input=$(dialog --title "Create Directory" --inputbox "Enter the directory name:" 8 40)
```

we get an empty screen! Why does this happen?

**Explanation:**

`dialog` outputs the user input on stderr, since stdout will already being used by ncurses to update the screen. Without output redirection being used, the command substitution will return the command's stdout into the variable - meaning the output of ncurses will not get printed on screen. However if you type something (you can't see anything while typing):

```
test<enter>
```

The text `test` will appear on screen. This happens because it will been written to stderr and stderr still points to the current terminal.

*Note:* You might expect the ncurses output in `$user_input` but `$user_input` is empty after the command. I assume that this happens because `dialog` will check if it's output is going to a tty and it won't output anything otherwise. (Haven't verfied that)

**Solution:**

We can exchange stderr and stdout using i/o rerouting. We will turn stderr into stdout and write the user input to the variable but on the other hand turn stdout into stderr which will make ncurses outputting to the screen:

```
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

In short: `3>&1` opens a new file descriptor which points to stdout, `1>&2` redirects stdout to stderr, `2>&3` points stderr to stdout and `3>&-` deletes the files descriptor `3` after the command has been executed.

This gives us the final command:

```
user_input=$(\
  dialog --title "Create Directory" \
         --inputbox "Enter the directory name:" 8 40 \
  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- \
)

mkdir "$user_input"
```

Comment: Can you explain this " 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-"

Comment: The rerouting effectively turns stderr into stdout and vice versa. This because `dialog` usually is using `stderr` for output.. (Just read that somewhere in the sources, currently I'm not sure why this should help, but hey! it works :) ... Let me figure that out...

Comment: It's in the manual - http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options (the `--stdout` and `--stderr` options)

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for the info (and for `dialog, it's nice! :) In the man page you wrote that you need to reopen the tty when using the `--stdout` option which will probably not work in some environments. Is the bash trick more portable? (Assuming that we have bash on all those platforms).

Comment: The redirection syntax is not a bash trick (it should work with any POSIX-shell).

Comment: I meant, would bash probably run into the same issues with reopening the tty? (I assume not). Is `dialog` using `isatty()` or something like that to decide whether ncurses output goes to a terminal or not? (I compiled the most basic ncurses program and ncurses output will get redirected to `$var` when using command substitution. This is not the case for `dialog`)

Comment: yes - see [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/util.c#L252)

Answer (score 1):

Note that Zenity is a GUI alternative.

If you looking for a text interface, fzf is really nice. You can easily redirect its output :

```
var=$(print -l folder/* | fzf)
```

If you just want to read user input :

```
var=$(echo '' | fzf --print-query)
```

It’s zsh syntax, bash users will translate it easily I suppose.

Also, fzf interacts well with tmux.